# NSURLSession background upload - need to enable background modes?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I am instantiating a `NSURLSession` to do several background uploads like this:

```
  sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];
```

Everything seems to work OK for the most part, but I am wondering if I need to add in the p.list the background Fetch key if all I am doing is background uploads and not downloads?. I am not able to find documentation saying that I should or that I should not. Specifically on XCode 5 +, I would like to know if under Capabilities>Background modes, I should enable or not background fetch, if all I am doing is background uploads, note that I do read the response after the upload is complete, which could be considered a "download".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official guide [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) declare three type of background executions:

1. **Executing Finite-Length Tasks** - using `UIApplication` method
   `beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:` to execute finite
   time task.
2. **Downloading Content in the Background** - using `NSURLSession` to
   download content. The `NSURLSession` provided by your app is run on
   separate system level daemon and when done, gets back to the app by
   the completion handler. (Your above mentioned implementation)
3. **Implementing Long-Running Tasks** - Tasks that needs to be running for
   long time, are handled under this category, like audio, voip,
   location, download processes, update contents. These type of tasks
   needs the special `UIBackgroundModes` key mentioned in info.plist.

So answering your question, you don't need the `UIBackgroundModes` key, until you don't fall in the long-running tasks category.